# How to fix error: resources file not found on run time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Resource file in my MVC5 project.

I use the resources files for localization.

Here is properties window of the resource file:

[image]

And here is Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources55))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources55),
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "FirstNameRequired")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources55),
                      ErrorMessageResourceName = "FirstNameLong")]

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LastName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources55))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources55),
              ErrorMessageResourceName = "LastNameRequired")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources55),
                      ErrorMessageResourceName = "LastNameLong")]

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And here is view that generates Person class:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>
```

On run time In this row:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

I get this error:

```
{"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"MvcInternationalization.App_GlobalResources.Resources55.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"MvcInternationalization\" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."}
```

Any Idea how to fix the error?